# Error pod 'SwiftLint'

Tags: cocoapods, swiftlint

> [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/1x/jmv798095x1fbjc_6128mflh0000gn/T/d20170314-59599-7fjizg/file.zip https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/download/0.16.1/portable_swiftlint.zip --create-dirs --netrc
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
>   Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   599    0   599    0     0    166      0 --:--:--  0:00:03
>   --:--:--   166   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:20 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to
>   github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com port 443: Operation timed out

This is the error when i execute `pod install`. My network is under socks5 proxy. I can download `https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/download/0.16.1/portable_swiftlint.zip` easily. But how can i pod success?

Comment: It looks a lot like you're having a network error when downloading a file GitHub is serving via Amazon S3. I'd suggest contacting GitHub, Amazon, or your ISP about this issue.

Comment: Still facing the same issue.. Please do tell whats next.